# change Skype background color in WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, skype, colors

I am running Windows 7,  I think the White background in Skype (contactlist and chat window) are way to bright and it annoys me.  But I find no way to change the color of it.

A work around I discovered is, If I right click on the desktop and Choose Personalize, and turn Aero of and select a HighContrast theme,  then I can set another background color of application Window.   Then Skype background will have that color.  Unfortunatley with Aero turned off webBrowsers like Firefox  cant render the graphics properly.

Im looking for a way to change Skype background with Aero still switched on.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Skype community thread](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-IM-window-fonts-and-background-color/td-p/1191076), it seems that is not possible.